# GKE Ingress Fails to Route Multiple Paths Under One Host

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I cannot get any of the paths under `- host: api.mysite.com` work with the GKE Ingress and I dont understand why. I get 404 when I try the routes.

With the sample below, I expect `api.mysite.com/v1/` and `api.mysite.com/v2/` to route to the appropriate services (which I exposed via nodeport). Unfortunately I'm only getting 404 returned to me.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gce-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-global-ip
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        serviceName: webserver
        servicePort: 8080
  - host: www.mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        serviceName: webserver
        servicePort: 8080
  - host: api.mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /v2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: api-v2
          servicePort: 9000
      - path: /v1/*
        backend:
          serviceName: api-v1
          servicePort: 8000
```

The nodeports exposing the services:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webserver
  labels:
    app: webserver
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: webserver
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: http
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-v2
  labels:
    app: api-v2
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: api-v2
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    name: http
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-v1
  labels:
    app: api-v1
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: api-v1
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    name: http
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

The results when I test the ingress (real hostname and ip redacted):

```
$ curl api.mysite.com/v1/ -v
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 123.123.123.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.mysite.com (123.123.123.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET /v1/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.mysite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
< Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 00:01:34 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 77
< Via: 1.1 google
<
{ [77 bytes data]
100    77  100    77    0     0     77      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   706
* Connection #0 to host api.mysite.com left intact
<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>
```

---

```
$ curl api.mysite.com/v2/ -v
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 123.123.123.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.mysite.com (123.123.123.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.mysite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
< Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 00:01:37 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 77
< Via: 1.1 google
<
{ [77 bytes data]
100    77  100    77    0     0     77      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   987
* Connection #0 to host api.mysite.com left intact
<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>
```

---

```
$ curl api.mysite.com/v1 -v
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 123.123.123.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.mysite.com (123.123.123.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET /v1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.mysite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 00:01:40 GMT
< Content-Length: 21
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Via: 1.1 google
<
{ [21 bytes data]
100    21  100    21    0     0     21      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   269
* Connection #0 to host api.mysite.com left intact
default backend - 404
```

---

```
$ curl api.mysite.com/v2 -v
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 123.123.123.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.mysite.com (123.123.123.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET /v2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.mysite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 00:01:44 GMT
< Content-Length: 21
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Via: 1.1 google
<
{ [21 bytes data]
100    21  100    21    0     0     21      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   333
* Connection #0 to host api.mysite.com left intact
default backend - 404
```

Comment: the ingress yaml seems to be ok, the service should answer via `api.mysite.com/v1/`   and `api.mysite.com/v1/`, maybe take a look again to the serviceName and Service port set up.

Comment: Can you add `-v` to the curl commands so we can see the sent / returned headers?

Comment: @cperez08 I added the definitions for the nodeports

Comment: Two other thoughts: Have you verified that the Service is responding on port 8000 or 9000 outside of the Ingress (ie. exec into a test pod and curl the ClusterIP of the Service)? Also, I notice the services are NodePort type. I know NodePort should create a ClusterIP in addition but maybe try changing them to ClusterIP instead.

Comment: @Will the definition seems to be ok as well, just to narrow down this, is your API exposing GET?, could you try to port forward your service so you can check via localhost if your apis are being exposed correctly?

```kubectl port-forward $podname 8000:8000 ```

Comment: @AndyShinn GKE Ingress works only with NodeIP (and LoadBalancer I think?) service. Tried it anyway, and from the GKE dashboard I got:  `error while evaluating the ingress spec:...is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer`.

Comment: @cperez08 just did that, and tested various API endpoints with GET, POST, PATCH. Works with no issue. I'm starting to think a fanout under a host rule is simply not supported by gke ingress, but I can't seem to find any documentation that confirms or rebukes this. So far, the closest example I've seen in the wild is a single path under a host rule.

Comment: I meant `NodePort` not `NodeIP` in an earlier comment

Comment: @Will last test, try using in your ingress paths just /v1 and v2 /

```- path: /v2``` and ```- path: /v1```

it is supposed to work in the way you have it according to GKE docs, however try using this way and let me know if works for you

Comment: :( @cperez08 
`$ curl api.dev.swiftlet.app/v1` returns `default backend - 404`
and
`$ curl api.dev.swiftlet.app/v1/` returns `Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.`

Comment: when i said trying with those paths i meant in the ingress def. change the  ingress yaml , deploy and test again, in case you did not do that.

Comment: @cperez08 yes that's what I did. I was simply sharing the indifferent responses from the service

Comment: Can you check the corresponding HTTP(S) Load balancer under Network Services > Load Balancing to make sure you have 4 paths and backends (default, webserver, apiv1, apiv2). Also, can you post the results of your checks against the service. Finally, what are you using for the API container? Are you using a framwork or a webserver? Does the application store HTTP request logs? I suspect the requests are looking for the path /v1/* in your container, is this how you have the pods configured or is the API stored in the root folder?

Comment: @PatrickW good lookout ;) I found something else while looking there (I'm Using Django with gunicorn). I had forgotten to reflect the changes to my url scheme in my django url configuration: `mysite.com/api/v1`(old) --> `api.mysite.com/v1`(new). That explains the html `<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>` being returned sometimes. I feel so silly right now.

Answer (score -1):

In order to reproduce the issue I followed the next documentation which explains how to setup HTTP Load balancing with Ingress, then as an optional thing you can reserve an static IP address and serving multiple application on the same Load Balancer.

It works fine for me following the above URL step by step:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Hope it works for you.